# C - index 13 out of bounds for type 'long long

Tags: c, indexoutofboundsexception, cs50

Hi I am a complete beginner to C.   I haven't been able to find the answer to the below on any forums.

Why am I getting the out of bounds error.  I've tried changing the type of array between int and long long to see if it makes a difference but hasn't s

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main (void)
{

 long long Cardnum;    
 long long n;
    int count = 0;
    printf("Enter Card Number: ");
    scanf("%lld", &Cardnum);
    n = Cardnum;
    while(n != 0)
    {
        // n = n/10
        n /= 10;
        ++count;
    }
    printf("Number of digits: %d\n", count);   

    if(count !=13 && count!=15 && count!=16)
    {

        printf("Invalid\n");
    }
    else     //Run luhns algo
    {
       printf("%lld\n",Cardnum); 
       long long numberArray[count]; 
      int c=0;
      int Digit=Cardnum; 

       while(Digit !=0) 
           {
           numberArray[count] = Digit%10;
           Digit/=10;
           c++;    
           }
    }


}
```

Comment: When working with card or telephone numbers it is easier when using a string. As a number, how many leading zeros are there? As a string, how easy is it to extract one field? You typed in the number digit by digit, the system converted that to a binary value, and then you go to that trouble breaking it back into digits, when you had them in the first place!

Comment: As a general comment, I suggest using a consistent case and capitalization. For example, why are `Digit` and `Cardnum` capitalized? And why is `numberArray` in camelCase but `Cardnum` isn't `cardNum`?

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning to `numberArray[count]`, but the last valid index is `numberArray[count - 1]`, since indices begin at `0`, so for `count == 13` there are thirteen indices: `0`…`12` (inclusive). Perhaps you meant to use `numberArray[c]` there.

Also note that `long long` is the type of the array's element, not of the array as a whole or its index. Indices are in units of the array's elements, i.e., even though `long long arr[n]` is larger in memory than `uint8_t arr[n]`, they both have `n` indices/elements. In this case `long long` is massive overkill when your elements are `% 10`.